# How to use jsconfig path with WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, shortcut

I am using WebStorm. 
On <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> I am able to jump to file of definition:

```
import myClass from '../../../../core/myClass';
```

But if I am using a `jsconfig.json` file, it doesn't work.

```
/// jsonfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Core/*": ["./app/bundles/core/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and in my file I replace with :

```
import myClass from 'Core/myClass';
```

Bundling is working perfectly, but not jump to file with WebStorm.

Any idea what settings ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`jsconfig.json` is not currently supported by the IDE, please follow [WEB-30581](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30581) and [WEB-36390](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36390) for updates

You can try a workaround from https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22717#focus=streamItem-27-1558931-0-0: create a file `config.js` (you can use a different name) in your project root, define the path mappings there, like:

```
System.config({
    "paths": {
        "Core/*": "./app/bundles/core/*"
    }
});
```

**Update**: path aliases defined in `jsconfig.json` are supported since 2019.2; see [WEB-36390](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36390)

Comment: I'm using `phpstorm` and `jsconfig.json` (`paths`) doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Have you found a solution for PHPStorm ?